# Finding hadith variants

Tags: hadith

Can someone help me where I can read the following sources? They concern the Hadith about holding fast to the Jama'ah. I just need to read the variants:

1. Al Mu’jamul Kabir, Hadith: 13623
2. Al Maqasidul Hasanah, Hadith: 1288

Links are enough.

Comment: You want to read the text of the hadith with the given numbers? [المعجم الكبير للطبراني 13623](https://ia600306.us.archive.org/32/items/WAQ15954/mtk12.pdf#page=447)
 and 
[المقاصد الحسنة 1288](https://ia600200.us.archive.org/28/items/FP159422/159422.pdf#page=716)

Comment: Jazak Allahu Khayran

Comment: Yes please. You can help quote the exact pages.

Comment: The links have the page numbers embedded into them so should open at the correct location. Anyways it is page 447 on the first one and 716 on the second one. Also the hadith numbers are the same, so if you can read Arabic numerals you should be able to get to them.

Comment: Can you also check this one : *Mustadrak Hakim, vol. 1 pg. 115*. The Hadith can be found there. I don't have the exact numbering, sorry.